# Return variable inside .forEach()

Tags: javascript, foreach

How can I access the scope inside foreach to grab the variable value ?

```
var fruitCollection = ['Grape','Orange','Banana'];

// give me a .txt file with the recipe for each fruit
var fruitsNeeded = function(){
    fruitCollection.forEach(function(fruit) {
        var fruitRecipe  = fruit.toLowerCase() + '.txt';

        return fruitRecipe;
    });
}

fruitsNeeded(); // undefined
```

**EDIT** Expected output:

```
// grape.txt
// orange.txt
// banana.txt
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying do to here. Do you want the fruitRecipe value for just the first fruit, or all of them? Have you tried using `.map()`?

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return the value from `forEach` function

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it **always** returns the value **undefined** and is not chainable.

You could use `map` function for it

```
var fruitCollection = ['Grape','Orange','Banana'];

var fruitsNeeded = function(){
    return fruitCollection.map(function(fruit) {
         return fruit.toLowerCase() + '.txt';
    });
}
```

ES6 snippet:

```js
var fruitCollection = ['Grape','Orange','Banana'];

var fruitsNeeded = () => fruitCollection.map(f => f.toLowerCase() + '.txt');

document.write(JSON.stringify(fruitsNeeded()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to build an array and return the whole array:

```
var fruitCollection = ['Grape','Orange','Banana'];

// give me a .txt file with the recipe for each fruit
var fruitsNeeded = function(){
    var fruitRecipeList = [];
    fruitCollection.forEach(function(fruit) {
        var fruitRecipe  = fruit.toLowerCase() + '.txt';
        fruitRecipeList.push(fruitRecipe);
    });
    return fruitRecipeList;
}

fruitsNeeded();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has no return value; it is simply a way to execute over an array. You probably want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var fruits = fruitCollection.map(function(fruit) {
  var fruitRecipe = fruit.toLowerCase() + '.txt';
  return fruitRecipe;
});
// fruits = ['grape.txt','orange.txt','banana.txt']
```

Comment: i think it's about one only

Comment: Getting only one value

Answer (score 0):

Rather then returning a value from the forEach, you can add them to another global scope variable.

Like this:

```
var fruitCollection = ['Grape','Orange','Banana'];
var fruitFiles = [] ;

// give me a .txt file with the recipe for each fruit
var fruitsNeeded = function(){
    fruitCollection.forEach(function(fruit) {
        var fruitRecipe  = fruit.toLowerCase() + '.txt';

        fruitFiles.push(fruitRecipe) ;
    });
return fruitFiles ;
}

fruitsNeeded(); // ["grape.txt", "orange.txt", "banana.txt"]
```

I hope this helps,
Jacob

Comment: I don't think using the global scope is the way to go

Comment: How come? I can see that this might get in the way of other variables, but other then that, I see no problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I see where you are coming from, thanks for pointing that out. I have also just realised that our answers are almost identical! And yours is probable better for not using the global scope.